# How to list images from a directory in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

My problem is this: I want to pick the images up from its diretory, independently of the number of them, and list it in a div through ul/li. I have tried by this below, but it is not showing neither the directory name, and the directory has 5 pictures. I have this code in HomeController :

```
public ActionResult ContactUs()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult ListImagesProducts()
{

        DirectoryInfo diretorio = new DirectoryInfo(@"~\Content\images\Products\");

        FileInfo[] Arquivos = diretorio.GetFiles("*.*");


        List<string> model = new List<string>();

        foreach (FileInfo fileinfo in Arquivos)
        {
            model.Add(fileinfo.Name);
        }

        var diretory = model;

        return Json(diretory, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And in the ContactUs view, I have this code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Three Jay - Produtos";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(getImages);
     function getImages() {
         $.getJSON("Home/ListImagesProducts", showImages);
     }

     function showImages(data) {
         for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
             var images = data[i];
             $("#diretoryImages").append("<li>" + images.toString + "</li>");
         }
     }

</script>
<div id = "diretoryImages" />
```

What am I doing wrong? You guys can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake, you are not calling function:

```
images.toString
```

add ()

```
images.toString()
```

In this particular case you don't even need to call `toString()`, because images variable is already string:

```
$("#diretoryImages").append("<li>" + images + "</li>");
```

Comment: @LucasBorsatto log `images` and see if it contains data

Comment: I have added Response.Write(fileInfo.Name) to my Controller and it show me the Images Filename. But I am just a beginner in web development, how can I log images in my view?

Comment: @LucasBorsatto you can write `console.log(images);` or write `debugger` and javascript execution will stop and you will be able to inspect element with chrome developer's tools